# Display data's in grid

Tags: windows, winforms

Hi am developing a Billing project(for one company) using C# windows application forms, In that am using DATAGRIDVIEW to display all the data's, But am trying to bind the values product wise that is given by user in the producttextbox with auto completion(that is if am giving A means it will display in the DATAGRID all the products that are related with A like A,AA,AAAA) i need a help to do......

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this...

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Components/UseanAutocompleteComboBox.htm